# A restricted view I can't turn off in Solid & Wireframe preview

Tags: 3d-view

For some reason I keep getting this strange restricted view only in solid & wireframe viewport mode. Doesn't appear in render preview. See the attached pics to see what I mean. Can anyone tell me what this is and how to remove it please. In solid preview:[image: In solid preview]

And in render preview:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've enabled a *Clipping Region*. Select it again from the menu or use shortcut <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> to clear it:

[image: Clip]